# Receiving Diffie-Hellman Key Over Sockets Error

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I've been doing a lot of research and cannot find a solution for this problem. I've spent hours and I can't figure it out, so I'm hoping someone here, who is more experienced than I am, can help. This program may not be the best practice, but it's for an assignment.

I am transmitting public keys using RSA, but more importantly, I'm trying to transmit Diffie Hellman parameters from Bob (the server) to Alice (the client). I am getting the following error when running the program:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   Inappropriate key specification   at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:85)
>     at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)     at
>   client.Client.main(Client.java:114) Caused by:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Error parsing key encoding     at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.DHPublicKey.(DHPublicKey.java:178)  at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:78)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.   at
>   sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
>     at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)   at
>   sun.security.util.DerValue.(DerValue.java:320)  at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.DHPublicKey.(DHPublicKey.java:125)  ...
>   3 more

Here is the code: 
Client.java:

```
package client;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.DHParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.*;


class Client{
    private static PublicKey publicKey = null;
    private static PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    private static PublicKey rsaBobPub = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyCipher = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyIntgSend = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyIntRecv = null; 
    private static KeyAgreement aKeyAgreement = null;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, `IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidKeySpecException{`
        Client client = new Client();
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
        byte[] alicePub;
        Cipher cipher2;
        byte[] encryptedDH = null;  
        byte[] bobEncryptedDH = null;
        OutputStream dh;
        InputStream bobDHConn;

            Socket connection = new Socket("localhost", 4129);

            //Generate Keys & then send to Bob
                keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                keyGen.initialize(2048);
                KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
                publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
                privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

           //Send Public Key to Bob
                ObjectOutputStream toBob = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                toBob.writeObject(publicKey);

           //Receive Bob's Public Key
                ObjectInputStream fromBob;
                fromBob = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                rsaBobPub = (PublicKey) fromBob.readObject();

  //SET UP DIFFIE HELLMAN PROTOCOL
  //For some reason, when receiving Bob's DH param, I am getting a lot of issues.
            //Exchange DH info
                DHParameterSpec paramSpec;
                AlgorithmParameterGenerator paramGen = AlgorithmParameterGenerator.getInstance("DH");
                paramGen.init(512);
                AlgorithmParameters parameters = paramGen.generateParameters();
                paramSpec = (DHParameterSpec) parameters.getParameterSpec(DHParameterSpec.class);

            //Generate Key Pair
                KeyPairGenerator aliceKpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
                aliceKpGen.initialize(paramSpec);
                KeyPair aliceKp = aliceKpGen.generateKeyPair();
                aKeyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
                aKeyAgreement.init(aliceKp.getPrivate());
                alicePub = aliceKp.getPublic().getEncoded();
                //System.out.println(aliceKp.getPublic())
                //System.out.println(aliceKp.getPublic().getEncoded())
                //Send Alice's encrypted DH byte info to Bob
               /*     cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                    cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaBobPub);
                    encryptedDH = cipher2.doFinal(alicePub);
                    System.out.print(encryptedDH);
                */
                    dh = connection.getOutputStream();
                    dh.write(alicePub);

             //Recieve Bob's DH Info
                bobDHConn = connection.getInputStream();
                int length;
                byte[] bobDH = null;


                while((length = bobDHConn.available()) == 0){
                    bobDH = new byte[length];
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < length){
                        i+= bobDHConn.read(bobDH, i, length - i);
                    }
                } 
          //NOT WORKING
           KeyFactory clientKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
           X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobDH);
           PublicKey bobsDHPubKey = clientKeyFac.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
           aKeyAgreement.doPhase(bobsDHPubKey, true);


        //Generate AES Secret Keys
        SecretKey aesKeyGen = aKeyAgreement.generateSecret("AES");


    }
}
```

Server.java

```
package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.DHPublicKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.DHParameterSpec;

public class Server{
    private static int port = 4129;
    private static PublicKey publicKey = null;
    private static PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    private static PublicKey rsaAlicePub = null;
    private static ServerSocket server = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyCipher = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyIntgSend = null;
    private static SecretKey SecretSharedKeyIntRecv = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
        //Declarations
            Server serv = new Server();
            server = new ServerSocket(4129);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
            byte[] cipherText = null;
            InputStream input = null;
            byte[] data = null;
            byte[] decryptedDH;
            InputStream DH = null;
            byte[] DHinfo = null;
            int length;
            byte[] aliceEncryptedDH = null;    
            SecretKey keyGenDH= null;
            InputStream aliceDH = null;
            Cipher cipher;
            PublicKey bobDHPub = null;
            OutputStream sendDH;

            //String message = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
            String message = "bbbbbbb";
            Socket client = server.accept();

            //Get Public Key froM Alice
                ObjectInputStream alicePK;
                alicePK = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                rsaAlicePub = (PublicKey)alicePK.readObject();

            //Generate Bob's keys
                keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                keyGen.initialize(2048);
                KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
                privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
                publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            //Send Bob's public Key to Alice
                ObjectOutputStream bobPK;
                bobPK = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                bobPK.writeObject(publicKey);

            //Exchange information for DH
            //Decrypt received information using Bob PK
            //You can assume that Bob selects the public parameters of Diffie‐Hellman protocol, and send them to Alice

            DH = client.getInputStream();
            while((length = DH.available()) == 0);
            int i = 0;
            DHinfo = new byte[length];
            while (i < length) {
                i += DH.read(DHinfo, i, length - i);
            }
/*
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            decryptedDH = cipher.doFinal(DHinfo);
           */ 
            KeyFactory clientKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
            X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(DHinfo);
            bobDHPub = clientKeyFac.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

            DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = ((DHPublicKey) bobDHPub).getParams();

            //Create Bob DH Keys
                KeyPairGenerator bobKpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
                bobKpGen.initialize(dhParamSpec);
                KeyPair bobsKeys = bobKpGen.generateKeyPair();

                KeyAgreement bobKeyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
                bobKeyAgreement.init(bobsKeys.getPrivate());
                bobKeyAgreement.doPhase(bobDHPub, true);

            //Send Bob's DH Parameters to Alice
            //send bobsKeys.getPublic().getEncoded()
                    sendDH = client.getOutputStream();
                    sendDH.write(bobsKeys.getPublic().getEncoded());

            //Encrypt message.getBytes();

    }

    private void Server() throws IOException{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);


    }



}
```

Comment: Does it work if you take sockets out of the equation?  In other words, if you write a single program that generates both sets of DH keys and does the exchange all within itself, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Your way of reading from an InputStream is wrong. First, you don't ever want to use the *available* method. It doesn't return what you think it returns, and what it returns is not useful for you.

When you write byte arrays to an OutputStream and you want the other side to reconstruct the same byte array, you need to tell the other side somehow how long the byte array is. The easiest way is to prefix it with the length.

In your case, you already have an ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream wrapped around your raw output and input streams. Just use them. Byte arrays are also objects, so you can call `writeObject` and `readObject` to transfer them.

In the client:

```
toBob.writeObject(alicePub);
```

And in the server:

```
DHinfo = (byte[]) alicePK.readObject();
```

(Note: you should rename `alicePk` to something like `fromAlice` if you use it for multiple purposes)